# Is there a way to refresh the page with anchor tab in same window

Tags: aurelia

Is there a way to refresh a page having an anchor tab in the same window? 
When opening same link in a new window, complete page is being load while in same window only the linked div is loading.

Comment: Aurelia is single page application framework, refreshing page will mean reload whole application ;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
We can reload the page in same window using below jquery function in method select() in your javascript.

select(){
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
    window.location.reload(true); 
});
return true;//It must return true
}

Second option: We can use aurelia event-aggregator to refresh other divs within same page
```

Comment: `window.location.reload` always reloads the whole page.

Comment: Yes, it will reload the page but here we need to reload after hashchange value with anchor link

Comment: But then what do you want to achieve with your question? I don't understand it, sorry.

Comment: <div id ="parent><div id="first> <a  rout-href="route: contact-detail; params.bind: {contactId: contactId, sublevelRoute:  'street-detail'}" click.trigger = 'reloadPageAfterHashChange(contactId)'>${contactId}</a></div><div id="second"></div></div>... When i clicked on anchor link ,its only refresh "first" div content but I need to refresh complete "parent" div. If i open the link in new window then the complete page is loaded but not in same window.My first div can have multiple anchors so I need to refresh same window after hash change with click event. I am using Aurelia JS.